raisebarno not working
It is needed to configure the \raisebarno parameter. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
%\setlyrics{Letras}{Jas-mi-nes en el pe-lo y ro-sas en la ca-ra ai-ro-sa ca-mi-na-ba la flor la flor de la ca-ne-la}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\generalsignature{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
%\setname1{Pno}
\setstaffs12
%\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\writebarno{\the\barno}%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
\def\raisebarno{6\internote}%
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
%\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=1%
\smallmusicsize
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\node (pointB) at (1.6,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
\node (pointC) at (6.4,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\hp|\zcn{q}{\hspace{-0.5cm}\bf\A Allegro}\ds\en%
\notes|\cu{g}\en%
\notes|\ibu0i1\qb0{i}\en%
\notes|\tbu0\qb0{k}\en\leftrepeat%\bar%
\notes\qu{D}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{H}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{f}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0h1\qb0{h}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{g}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0i1\qb0{i}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\alaligne
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
        \node (pointB) at (4.25,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
        \node (pointC) at (9.15,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7/ii}}};
        \draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.95,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\qu{H}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\cl{j}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\en
\notes|\cl{j}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ql{l}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\hl{i}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\en
\notes|\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\ds\en
\notes|\cl{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{^k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en\bar
\notes\qu{E}|\zcn{K}{\B E}\ibl0m0\qb0{^m}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{m}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\lsh{N}\ql{N}|\cl{m}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\ql{N}|\en
\notes|\cl{k}\en
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The command: \def\raisebarno{6\internote}% is not working.
The current output is as follow:


You must use: musixflx command

Please compare and learn to play yourself (and run it yourself to see the output):
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
%\setlyrics{Letras}{Jas-mi-nes en el pe-lo y ro-sas en la ca-ra ai-ro-sa ca-mi-na-ba la flor la flor de la ca-ne-la}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\generalsignature{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
%\setname1{Pno}
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
%
%\def\writebarno{\the\barno}%
%
%\def\raisebarno{12\internote}%
%\systemnumbers%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
%\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=0%
\smallmusicsize
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\node (pointB) at (1.6,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
\node (pointC) at (6.4,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\hp|\zcn{q}{\hspace{-0.5cm}\bf\A Allegro}\ds\en%
\notes|\cu{g}\en%
\notes|\ibu0i1\qb0{i}\en%
\notes|\tbu0\qb0{k}\en\leftrepeat%\bar%
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{36}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{35}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{H}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{f}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0h1\qb0{h}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{34}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{33}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{g}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0i1\qb0{i}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\alaligne
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
        \node (pointB) at (4.25,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
        \node (pointC) at (9.15,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7/ii}}};
        \draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.95,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\qu{H}|\hbsk\zcharnote{r}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{35}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\cl{j}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\en
\notes|\cl{j}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\hbsk\zcharnote{a}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\zcn{K}{\B G}\ql{l}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\hl{i}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\en
\notes|\en\bar
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote f{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\ds\en
\notes|\cl{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{^k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en\bar
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote c{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{E}|\zcn{K}{\B E}\ibl0m0\qb0{^m}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{m}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\lsh{N}\ql{N}|\cl{m}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\ql{N}|\en
\notes|\cl{k}\en
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

This would be my MusiXTeX version: less lines, more visual separators, a definition of the place for the bar numbers, if desired. Besides: don't count an upbeat as measure!
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
%\setlyrics{Letras}{Jas-mi-nes en el pe-lo y ro-sas en la ca-ra ai-ro-sa ca-mi-na-ba la flor la flor de la ca-ne-la}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\generalsignature{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
%\setname1{Pno}
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\bnr{\hbsk\zcharnote{36}{\A\the\barno}\hsk}%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
%
%\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=0%
\smallmusicsize
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\def\atnextbar{\znotes\centerbar{\hpause}|\en}%
\notes\zcharnote{-15}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\node (pointB) at (1.6,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
\node (pointC) at (6.4,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}|\zcn{q}{\hspace{-0.5cm}\bf\A Allegro}\ds\cu{g}\ibl0i3\qb0{i}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\leftrepeat%
%
\notes\bnr\qu{D}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en%\hbsk\zcharnote{36}{\A\the\barno}\hsk
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en%
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar%
%
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{35}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{H}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en%
\notes\sk\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\sk\ds\cu{f}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0h3\qb0{h}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\bar%
%
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{34}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en%
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en%
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar%
%
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{33}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en%
\notes\sk\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\sk\ds\cu{g}\en%
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0i1\qb0{i}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\alaligne%
%
\notes\zcharnote{-15}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
        \node (pointB) at (4.25,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
        \node (pointC) at (9.15,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7/ii}}};
        \draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.95,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\qu{H}|\hbsk\zcharnote{r}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en%
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0{k}\en%
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar%
%
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote{35}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en%
\notes\sk\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\sk\cl{j}\ql{k}\en%
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\sk\cl{j}\en\bar%
%
\notes\qu{G}|\hbsk\zcharnote{a}{\A\the\barno}\hsk\zcn{K}{\B G}\ql{l}\en%
\notes\sk\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\sk\hl{i}\en%
\notes\sk\zq{Nb}\ql{d}\sk|\en\bar%
%
\notes\hbsk\zcharnote f{\A\the\barno}\hsk\qu{D}|\ds\cl{l}\en%
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{^k}\tbl0\qb0{l}\en%
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{k}\tbl0\qb0{l}\en\bar%
%
\notes\bnr\qu{E}|\zcn{K}{\B E}\ibl0m0\qb0{^m}\tbl0\qb0{m}\en%
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\lsh{N}\ql{N}|\cl{m}\ql{k}\en%
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\ql{N}|\sk\cl{k}\en%
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}%
\end{document}%


I substituted my first answer by the complete code. Please compare this:
\documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
%\setlyrics{Letras}{Jas-mi-nes en el pe-lo y ro-sas en la ca-ra ai-ro-sa ca-mi-na-ba la flor la flor de la ca-ne-la}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\generalsignature{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
%\setname1{Pno}
\setstaffs12
%\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
%
%\def\writebarno{\the\barno}%
%
\systemnumbers%
\def\raisebarno{2\internote}%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
%\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=1%
\smallmusicsize
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\node (pointB) at (1.6,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
\node (pointC) at (6.4,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\hp|\zcn{q}{\hspace{-0.5cm}\bf\A Allegro}\ds\en%
\notes|\cu{g}\en%
\notes|\ibu0i1\qb0{i}\en%
\notes|\tbu0\qb0{k}\en\leftrepeat%\bar%
\notes\qu{D}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{H}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{f}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0h1\qb0{h}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{g}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0i1\qb0{i}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\alaligne
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
        \node (pointB) at (4.25,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
        \node (pointC) at (9.15,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7/ii}}};
        \draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.95,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\qu{H}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\cl{j}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\en
\notes|\cl{j}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ql{l}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\hl{i}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\en
\notes|\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\ds\en
\notes|\cl{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{^k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en\bar
\notes\qu{E}|\zcn{K}{\B E}\ibl0m0\qb0{^m}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{m}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\lsh{N}\ql{N}|\cl{m}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\ql{N}|\en
\notes|\cl{k}\en
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

to
    \documentclass[border=8pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
%\setlyrics{Letras}{Jas-mi-nes en el pe-lo y ro-sas en la ca-ra ai-ro-sa ca-mi-na-ba la flor la flor de la ca-ne-la}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\generalsignature{1}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}4}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
\staffbotmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
%\setname1{Pno}
\setstaffs12
%\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
%
%\def\writebarno{\the\barno}%
%
\def\raisebarno{12\internote}%
\systemnumbers%
\renewcommand\fontbarno{\A}%
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
%\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=1%
\smallmusicsize
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
%\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{2}{Letras}
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\node (pointB) at (1.6,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
\node (pointC) at (6.4,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
\draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\hp|\zcn{q}{\hspace{-0.5cm}\bf\A Allegro}\ds\en%
\notes|\cu{g}\en%
\notes|\ibu0i1\qb0{i}\en%
\notes|\tbu0\qb0{k}\en\leftrepeat%\bar%
\notes\qu{D}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{H}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{f}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0h1\qb0{h}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ds\en
\notes|\cu{g}\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\ibl0i1\qb0{i}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en\alaligne
\notes\zcharnote{-18}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (pointA) at (0,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V}}};
        \node (pointB) at (4.25,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{I}}};
        \node (pointC) at (9.15,0) {\textcolor{red-undar}{\textbf{V7/ii}}};
        \draw[red-undar,thick, line width=0.8mm] (pointA) -- (pointB) -- (pointC) -- (10.95,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}\qu{H}|\zcn{K}{\B D}\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\ibl0j1\qb0{j}\en
\notes|\tbl0\isluru0k\qb0{k}\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\tslur0k\ql{k}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\cl{j}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{da}\lq{c}\ql{M}|\en
\notes|\cl{j}\en\bar
\notes\qu{G}|\zcn{K}{\B G}\ql{l}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\hl{i}\en
\notes|\en
\notes\zq{Nb}\ql{d}|\en
\notes|\en\bar
\notes\qu{D}|\ds\en
\notes|\cl{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{^k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en
\notes\qp|\ibl0k{1}\qb0{k}\en%
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{l}\en\bar
\notes\qu{E}|\zcn{K}{\B E}\ibl0m0\qb0{^m}\en
\notes|\tbl0\qb0{m}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\lsh{N}\ql{N}|\cl{m}\en
\notes|\ql{k}\en
\notes\zq{be}\lq{d}\ql{N}|\en
\notes|\cl{k}\en
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

In lines 23-24 I changed the orde and the amount of \raisebarno. The effect should be obvious: both orders work, and the raise works well. The point is: you want every bar numbered. This is not provided for by MusiXTeX without changing the general code in musixtex.tex or by writing own code (or numbering the bars manually).

\systemnumbers%
\def\raisebarno{6\internote}%
not working also...

Exactly, it is needed that every bar numbered.
